# Bad quality on tabBarItem image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, icons

I am adding image for my tabBarItem

```
playerViewController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Icon-Small")
```

"Icon-small" it's 29 × 29 PNG image

And when I'm running my app quality of this image in tabBarItem very low.
If I'm using 50x50 it's too big and also low quality.
All icons prepared from 512x512 PNG with Prepo Mac application.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using 2x and 3x images? If not then try with it.

Another solution is to use .pdf file in vector format. It will stretch your image as needed.

[image]